# how to append in excel sheet and process further

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7, web-scraping

Below program will open the excel file I saved in local, and open the url one by one in delay of 2 seconds.

I need to change with item name instead of URL.

Example: previous input is https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07JH6RJ36/ and it open every links

New input : **B07JH6RJ36** so here I need every cells append with **https://www.amazon.in/dp/** so it can open each site by row as it is.

Please help to get this right.

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui, time
import xlrd
URL = []
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
loc = ("C:\\Users\\dilip\\PycharmProjects\\untitled3\\URL.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
#open the first sheet
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    URL.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))

for i in range(0, len(URL)):
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(URL[i])
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

xlrd is only for reading, not modifying, Excel files and no longer supports `.xlsx` files.

Your problem is better solved by using https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, which can work with `.xlsx` files and can both read and write those files.